# Get all $??? occurrence in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How do I get all words starting with $ (it's not a variable)?

This is what I've got, but it doesn't return the words. Can anyone help me?

```
$str = 'Lorem $ipsum dolor sit $amet, consectetur adipiscing $elit. Fusce nec turpis magna, in tempor sem. Duis porttitor $feugiat ligula, in vehicula nunc pellentesque vel. Morbi consectetur pretium lorem. Vivamus nunc mauris, consequat vel condimentum vel, lobortis sit amet eros. Fusce hendrerit adipiscing justo at scelerisque. $Phasellus sed convallis $tellus. In sed lacus ac nulla bibendum scelerisque.';

preg_match("/(\$[a-z]+)/i", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: preg_match_**all** and proper quoting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/(\$[a-z]+)/i', $str, $matches);
```

`preg_match_all` to fin ALL occurrences, single quotes to make `\$` be correctly read.

```
'/(\$\w+)/'
```

might be even better.

Comment: I'm getting two arrays from `$matches` with same data. See http://www.pastelib.com/show/9aEYxHwN Why is this?

Comment: Sure you do, you have brackets (in your OQ) - if you don't want them, use `'/\$\w+/'`

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all()`? (Like in [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php))

Comment: `\$` in double quotes won't be affected by that.